# Makefile not reading a timestamp variable

Tags: windows, spring-boot, makefile, migration, liquibase

I would like to add a **Makefile** in my project to use the **make command** for my migrations, the file generated should have a **timestamp and a label as a name**, but when I run the make command the **timestamp is not appearing** in the file name.

Here's the Makefile script:

```
MIGRATION_LABEL = "to-be-changed"
DATE_WITH_TIME := $(shell /bin/date "+%Y%m%d%H%M%S")

makeMigration:
    mvn liquibase:diff -DdiffChangeLogFile=src/main/resources/db/changelog/changes/${DATE_WITH_TIME}-${MIGRATION_LABEL}.yml
    @echo "  - include:" >> src/main/resources/db/changelog/db.changelog-master.yml
    @echo "      file: classpath*:db/changelog/changes/$(DATE_WITH_TIME)-$(MIGRATION_LABEL).yml" >> src/main/resources/db/changelog/db.changelog-master.yml
```

and here is the error :

```
C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\Project\project-backend>make makeMigration MIGRATION_LABEL="user-creation"
File path not found.
mvn liquibase:diff -DdiffChangeLogFile=src/main/resources/db/changelog/changes/-user-creation.yml
```

I would like to see a timestamp before "-user-creation.yml"

Comment: You are running on Windows.  There's no `/bin/date` on Windows.

Comment: I see thanks, but what should I write instead ?

Comment: Don't know: you should add tags to your question so that Windows people will help you out... I almost never use Windows myself.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things that might help here.   First, you set `DATE_WITH_TIME` using `:=`, which does an [immediate expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Reading-Makefiles.html).   If you have a really long build, this will represent the time the makefile was first read, as opposed to the time the recipe is run.   Not sure if this is your intent.   You likely want deferred expansion.

Next, the windows version of date and time will look like this (based off of https://www.windows-commandline.com/get-date-time-batch-file/):

```
DATE_WITH_TIME = $(shell echo %date%:%time%)
```

Last, if you want to test this quickly and easily, you can use the `$(info ...)` makefile directive:

```
DATE_WITH_TIME = $(shell echo %date%:%time%)
$(info DATE_WITH_TIME right now is $(DATE_WITH_TIME))
```

which will print a log in your output so you know if you've made a mistake early on, without having to actually build anything.